# Sum of xor of all subsequences in an array

Tags: arrays, bit-manipulation, xor

I have an array of length say N(upto 10^5) and each element in it can be upto 10^9. Now i want know if there's some techniques or fast algorithm through which I can find sum of xor of all subsequences of the array.
For example,
if N is 3
The elements are 1, 2, 3.
So the subsequences will be {1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3} and xor sum of all these equals to 12.
Pls help...

Comment: Your example shows subsets, not subsequences. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

Since your example basically shows xor sum of al subsets.
Why dont you see this :
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712487/finding-xor-of-all-subsets